# jQuery appended element with class styling only partially working

Tags: jquery, css, append

I have a CSS file with a class:

```
.item { 
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

In jQuery I am appending a new `div` with a `class="item"`:

```
new_item = '<div id="item' + num_items + '" class="ui-widget-content item"></div>';
$('div#scene').append(new_item);
```

The `div` is appended with the proper height and width but the background color is white rather than blue as specified from the CSS file.

Why is the appended `div` being styled with the correct height and width but not `background-color`?

Comment: [That works](http://jsfiddle.net/8dhv3Lbe/), the problem is in code or CSS you haven't shown.

Comment: In any half-decent browser, right-click the element and choose "Inspect element" Then look at the CSS or Style tab, it will tell you what rules are being applied, and which are being overridden by others.

Comment: Thanks!  I wasn't aware I could see which styles were being overridden.  That really helps.  I was able to figure out Atud was somewhat correct and ui-widget-content was overriding the background color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like the specificity of the CSS rules from the `.item` class is not high enough to override any existing rules set on the element. You can try making the selector more specific:

```
#parentElement div.item { 
     width: 100px;
     height: 100px;
     background-color: blue;
}
```

Or use the `!important` flag:

```
.item { 
     width: 100px;
     height: 100px;
     background-color: blue !important;
}
```

Note that the former is by far the better practice. The use of `!important` should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: Huh, Perfect.  Thank you!  You solved my day long headache in less than a minute.. Bravo!

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score -1):

Try

.ui-widget-content.item{
....your css here...
}

because ui-widget-content has some extra css rules.